Neumann problem for the Laplacian with Dirac delta functions
I have encountered a problem while dealing with the adjoint method in potential flow that is also described, in a similar fashion, in (eq. 39) of this paper. The problem is essentially this:
$$\begin{cases} 
      \Delta f= 0 & B \\
      \partial_n f=\delta(x-x_0) & \partial B^+ \\
      \partial_n f=-\delta(x-x_0) & \partial B^-. \\
         \end{cases}$$
$B$ is the domain exterior to a unit disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function, $x_0$ is the point $(1,0)$, and $\partial B^\pm$ are the half-circles corresponding to the non-negative (resp. negative) values of the Cartesian coordinate $y$. I can't really make sense of this and I'm inclined to think that the problem is somehow ill-defined or has a trivial solution, but I don't know how to proceed. Any clues?

So you want a harmonic function on the complement of the closed disk that has... in some reasonable sense, boundary values on the circle being $\pm \delta$ functions at two boundary points? But, then, quantitatively, I don't quite understand the formulaic description... isn't there a conflict of sign at the point $(1,0)$?

I don't see a conflict of sign, just a discontinuous Neumann boundary condition involving a delta function. I understand it as $\partial_n f = g$ for $y\geq 0$ and $\partial_n f = -g$ for $y<0$, where $g$ is the Dirac delta at (1,0). Having said that, I recall that the conjugate Poisson kernel $$
\tilde P= \frac{2r\sin\theta}{1+r^2-2r\cos\theta}
$$
has a similar behavior on the circle ($r=1$), $\partial_n \tilde P = 0$, except at $\theta=0$ where it has a singularity (but it's not a pair of delta functions but a $1/\theta$ singularity).

It occurs to me that perhaps one can split the problem in two
$$\begin{cases} 
      \Delta f^+= 0 & B \\
      \partial_n f^+=\delta(x-x_0) & \partial B \\
         \end{cases}$$
and
$$\begin{cases} 
      \Delta f^-= 0 & B \\
      \partial_n f^-=-\delta(x-x_0) & \partial B \\
         \end{cases}$$
and use Poisson formula
$$
f(x)=-\frac{1}{\pi}  \int_{\partial B} \partial_n f(y) \log\vert x-y\vert dy
$$
for the Neumann problem to each case and then add the solutions. For each of the problems separately, the formal solution would be
$$
f^\pm=\mp \frac{1}{\pi}\log\vert x-x_0\vert
$$
so, apparently, the total solution $f^++f^-=0$. One has of course to be careful when dealing with this delta functions, and, besides, each of the subproblems is probably not well defined as
$$
\int_{\partial B} \partial_n f(y) dy \ne 0
$$
but I guess this could be arranged by adding or subtracting 1 from the Dirac delta in the Neumann b.c. for each subproblem, which would still yield $f^++f^-=0$. I am aware that the argument is a bit sloppy, but this is the first thing that came to mind.
Alternatively, one can split the singularity as follows
$$\begin{cases} 
      \Delta f= 0 & B \\
      \partial_n f =\delta(x-x_\epsilon)-\delta(x-x_{-\epsilon}) & \partial B \\
         \end{cases}$$
where $x_{\pm\epsilon}=(\cos\epsilon,\pm\sin\epsilon)$ (with $\epsilon <<1)$ and use again Poisson formula to solve the problem with the same (zero) result.
